# How to change a table value in HTML based on a select option?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to modify the price based on the selected Model.

```js
const options = {
  'Toyota': {
    cars: ['Camry', 'Corolla', 'Yaris Sedan']
  },
  'Nissan': {
    cars: ['bluebird', 'Murano', 'Tiida']
  },
  'Volkswagen': {
    cars: ['MarkX', 'Avensis']
  },

}

function updateCarByBrand() {
  carselect.innerHTML = "";
  options[brandselect.value].cars.forEach(e => carselect.innerHTML += `<option value=${e}">${e}</option>`)
}
brandselect.addEventListener('change', updateCarByBrand);
updateCarByBrand();



if (cars = 'Camry') {
  document.getElementById("washing").innerHTML = 20;
  document.getElementById("polishing").innerHTML = 20;
} else {
  document.getElementById("washing").innerHTML = 0;
  document.getElementById("polishing").innerHTML = 0;
}

if (cars = 'Corolla') {
  document.getElementById("washing").innerHTML = 30;
  document.getElementById("polishing").innerHTML = 30;
} else {
  document.getElementById("washing").innerHTML = 0;
  document.getElementById("polishing").innerHTML = 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Factory <br>

  <select id="brandselect">
    <option value="Toyota"> Toyota</option>
    <option value="Nissan"> Nissan</option>
    <option value="Volkswagen"> Volkswagen</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p>Model <br>
  <select id="carselect">
  </select>
</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Choice </th>
    <th>Service </th>
    <th>Price $ </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Washing</td>
    <td>
      <p id="washing"></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Polishing</td>
    <td>
      <p id="polishing"></p>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another event listener and a price object

You could embed the price in the car object but here you can have a default for models you do not want to have special prices for

```js
const options = {
  'Toyota': {
    cars: ['Camry', 'Corolla', 'Yaris Sedan']
  },
  'Nissan': {
    cars: ['bluebird', 'Murano', 'Tiida']
  },
  'Volkswagen': {
    cars: ['MarkX', 'Avensis']
  },
}
const prices = {
  "Camry": {
    "washing": 20,
    "polishing": 20
  },
  "Corolla": {
    "washing": 30,
    "polishing": 30
  },
}

function updateCarByBrand() {
  carselect.innerHTML = "";
  options[brandselect.value].cars.forEach(car => carselect.innerHTML += `<option value="${car}">${car}</option>`)
}

function updatePriceByModel() {
  const cars = carselect.value;
  let price = prices[cars] || {
    "washing": 0,
    "polishing": 0
  }; // default
  console.log(cars,price)
  document.getElementById("washing").innerHTML = price.washing;
  document.getElementById("polishing").innerHTML = price.polishing;
}
brandselect.addEventListener('change', updateCarByBrand);
updateCarByBrand();
carselect.addEventListener('change', updatePriceByModel);
updatePriceByModel()
```

```html
<p>Factory <br>

  <select id="brandselect">
    <option value="Toyota"> Toyota</option>
    <option value="Nissan"> Nissan</option>
    <option value="Volkswagen"> Volkswagen</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p>Model <br>
  <select id="carselect">
  </select>
</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Choice </th>
    <th>Service </th>
    <th>Price $ </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Washing</td>
    <td>
      <p id="washing"></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Polishing</td>
    <td>
      <p id="polishing"></p>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```